# Why is my Java program not running?

Tags: java, arrays

The following program swaps two elements in an array. But it does not seem to run, but I am sure that I am not doing anything wrong.

```
public class swap {

    public static String[] swap(int first, int second, String[] A) {
        String hold = A[first];
        A[first] = A[second];
        A[second] = hold;
        return A;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] B = {"Dawn", "Justice", "Of"};
        String[] c = swap.swap(1, 2, B);
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is, but your printing the arrays `toString` (or equivalent) output, not it's contents, try using `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(c));` instead

Comment: any errors when you run?

Comment: ERROR: [Ljava.lang.String;@659e0bfd

Comment: @3kings The output is `[Ljava.lang.String;@2a139a55`, not what the OP is expecting (which I believe they want to see `[Dawn, Of, Justice]`)

Comment: @KenSlade Thought that two, but there are 3 elements in the array and the OP wants to swap `Justice` and `of`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Need to create Object of `swap class`, or since it is `static` no need to create object, just use `swap(1, 2, B);`

2.) Print `Arrays.toString(c)`

**Modified Code**

```
public static String[] swap(int first, int second, String[] A) {
        String hold = A[first];
        A[first] = A[second];
        A[second] = hold;
        return A;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] B = { "Dawn", "Justice", "Of" };
        String[] c = swap(1, 2, B);
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(c));

    }
```

**output**

```
[Dawn, Of, Justice]
```

Comment: Point one is void, as `swap` is `static` and doesn't rely on anything that isn't passed to it

Comment: @MadProgrammer yup correct, modified

Answer (score -1):

import java.util.Arrays;
public class swap {

```
public static String[] swap(int first, int second, String[] A) {
    String hold = A[first];
    A[first] = A[second];
    A[second] = hold;
    return A;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] B = {"Dawn", "Justice", "Of"};
    String[] c = swap.swap(1, 2, B);
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(c));
}
```

}